Algorithm for coordinate transformation from XYZ to Forward/Up/Right based on user-specified directions
Hopefully this question is not too broad. I am not looking for anyone to write this algorithm for me, but hopefully what I'm trying to do here has been done already and I failed to find it, and I hope someone could suggest how such problems are typically solved.
I am writing an application that takes a 3D model from a CAD program, reads geometric data, and performs calculations on it. In 3D space, coordinates are represented as positive/negative XYZ values, and I have a wrapper for storing them:
public class XyzCoords
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;
}

Suppose that user made a 3D model of a car. Depending on how they modelled it, it might be facing X+, X-, Y+, Y-, Z+ or Z- direction, and the roof might be pointing to any other direction. User needs to specify Forward/Up directions in my application so it can make sense of the model and perform calculations on it. Directions are represented as enumerator:
public enum Directions
{
    Xpos,
    Xneg,
    Ypos,
    Yneg,
    Zpos,
    Zneg
}

And user selection is saved in settings like this:
public Directions directionFw;
public Directions directionUp;

(Right is not necessary to specify, as it can be extrapolated from Forward/Up)
To make calculations and results direction-agnostic, I have another coordinate wrapper that represents coordinates as Forward/Up/Right:
public class FurCoords
{
    public double F;
    public double U;
    public double R;
}

Now, I need a converter that can convert from XyzCoords to FurCoords and back:
public static class XyzFurConverter
{
    public FurCoordinates Convert(XyzCoords xyzCoords, Directions directionFw, Directions directionUp)
    {
        //...
    }

    public XyzCoords Convert(FurCoordinates coordinates, Directions directionFw, Directions directionUp)
    {
        //...
    }
}

In my application core, Z positive is considered Forward, and Y positive is considered Up, which makes X positive Right. Meaning that if the first function were called like this:
FurCoords furCoords = XyzFurConverter.Convert([1, 2, 3], Directions.Zpos, Directions.Ypos)

Then FurCoords field values should be written like this:
F = 1
U = 2
R = 3

Problem is implementing the conversion. It can certainly be done with a load of if/switch statements for every possible combination, but that seems a dumb way to go about it, considering the sheer number of combinations. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and could suggest how such thing is typically solved? Again, not looking for anyone to do my homework for me, just some guidance.

I do something similar; but in 2D; and the end result is an Enum. If the angle of rotation is "zero" (for example), it's "FacingFront" (enum). If rotation = 180, it's "FacingAbout"; etc.   And which naturally leads to "commands" like "FaceFront" or FaceAbout; etc. It gets more involved: the "front" may be in one direction, but movement is in another; e.g. ByTheFront; ByTheLeft (flank). Makes code certainly more readable versus: "move at 90 degrees"; etc. Rotation is "generally" in 1/16 increments; so "direction" can generally be infered as in compass points (Left vs "west", leftTop; etc.)

The "logic" is incorporated into the object; e.g. if ( myObject.IsFacingFront ) { myObject.FaceAbout(); etc. }

You might want to take a look at system.numerics or Math.Net spatial

This problem is generally solved with the use of transformation matrices.
It does require a bit of algebra, but once you get the hang of it it's quite easy. The basic idea is that a matrix-vector multiplication transforms the object from one coordinate system into another. Starting from the homogeneous 4-dimensional(unless you only need rotations and never translations, in which case a 3d matrix works as well) identity matrix
(1 0 0 0)
(0 1 0 0)
(0 0 1 0)
(0 0 0 1)

(which does nothing when applied to an object) you can start out swapping coordinates. E.g. to flip the object upside down, you negate the z-axis:
(1 0 0 0)
(0 1 0 0)
(0 0 -1 0)
(0 0 0 1)

Of course, it's better to apply a rotation around the x axis instead (as the above "flip" inverses left and right). That would look like
     (1 0 0 0)
Rx = (0 cos(180) sin(180) 0)
     (0 -sin(180) cos(180) 0)
     (0 0 0 1)

Once you've set up your matrix (in your case, using whatever rotation values the user provides), you then multiply the matrix with the vector of every point (you need to use 4-dimensional vectors, the 4th element must be 1 at the beginning, but can be ignored afterwards).
For each point:
FurCoords[1x4-Vector] = XyzCoords[1x4-Vector] * Matrix[4x4-Matrix]

A good algebra book (or an existing math library) will tell you how to do a vector times matrix multiplication.
